# Hoisting in a self-calling function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know the general rule of hoisting, variables and functions are hoisted during the compile phase.

Hence anything written as the following

```
var foo = 'global';
```

will be compiled as,

```
var foo; // Undefined
foo = 'global'; // Declared
```

but this is what I am unable to understand

---

```
var foo = 'global';
var myObject = {
    foo: 'local',
    func: function(){
        console.log(this.foo); // Local
        (function(){
            console.log(this.foo); // Global
        })();
    }
}
myObject.func();
```

Why is the self-calling function inside `myObject` printing the global foo/ taking the context of window?

What in general I am trying to understand is where is it getting hoisted.

Comment: Because `this` inside the IIFE is `window`. The execution context in which it is invoked is the global context. This is because the function not invoked on an object such as `obj.func()` so `this` by default refers to `window`.

Comment: Shouldn't the self invoking function only be executed when obj.func() is declared.

Comment: @patz it has nothing todo with hoisting. Your understanding of *context* doesnt fit to js...

Answer (score 1):

Add `console.log(this);` before the call to `console.log(this.foo)` and you will see that `this` is essentially just `window`. This is why you're getting the global `foo`.

The default value of `this` in a function is the "global object" when invoked directly; in a browser, the global object is `window`. You will see `window` in this case as well:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}
foo();
```

Since you've defined a function-expression and have invoked it immediately, it's essentially invoking the function directly (similar to the way you would invoke a regular function directly).

Comment: But maybe explain why it's `window`...?

Comment: @AndrewLi Just added a line explaining why.

Comment: the question is more on the self invoking function. is the self invoking function hoisted outside/above the top of myObject.

Comment: @patz IIFE involves a *function expression* and so it is not hoisted.

Answer (score 1):

Window is a global context within which everything is executed (in general).

Whatever you declare outside of a function (or in a function without `var`) is treated as a property (method) of a global object.

For example, when you call `setTimeout(foo, 1000)` or `setInterval(foo, 1000)`, it's treated as `window.setTimeout(foo, 1000)` and `window.setInterval(foo, 1000)` accordingly.

This part:

```
func: function(){
  console.log(this.foo); // local
  (function(){ 
     console.log(this.foo); // global
  })();
```

When you invoke the first `console.log`, it's invoked inside of a function which's the object's method. The next `console.log` is invoke inside of **another** function which isn't "on the same level" as `func` so by default its invocation conext is global object.

Of course, you can store the reference to the object itself by putting the following line:

```
var self = this
```

So the code will look as follows:

```
func: function(){
  console.log(this.foo); // local
  var self = this;
  (function(){ 
     console.log(self.foo); // now it's local
  })();
```

2.

> the question is more on the self invoking function. is the self invoking function hoisted outside/above the top of myObject.

In your particular case **no**

Hoisting is about **variables declaration inside of functions**.

Object declaration isn't the same thing. `func` is just a property of an object. Hoisting can be met in the function definition:

```
foo = "global";
var test = function(){
    var foo;
    // Declared but not defined
    console.log(foo);
    foo = 'local';
    // Now it's defined. Thanking to functional scope, the function "sees" local variable
    console.log(foo);
}
```

Or even better:

```
foo = 'global';
var test = function(){
    console.log(foo); // undefined, but declared
    var foo;

    foo = 'local';
    console.log(foo);
}
```